# Chrome Extension: access separate html documents from contentscript

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that loads/injects a contentscript.js This script appends html and css to the webpage.

Currently I have the html and css written into my contentscript. What I would like is for the css itself, as well as the body of my new elements to be in separate document, mostly so it looks better than having html and css as text in a .js document.

Then in the contentscript I would do something like

```
node = the_html_doc.html
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(node);
```

But how do I access such a separate document from my contentscript? It needs to be available in all tabs (I use the activeTab permission), not just the url in the manifest "matches".

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be to use a background script. What I did was to make a file called `background.html` that would store nothing but templates. I then had my background script (`background.js`) setup to communicate with my content script (`content.js`). The content script would send a message to the background script with a `command` indicating it wants a template. Leveraging jQuery, i can easily select and return a template to my content script which can then be injected into the page.

Here is the code (bits an pieces):

**background.html**

```
<div id="template-1"></div>
<div id="template-2"></div>
...
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(cmd, sender, sendResponse){
    c = JSON.parse(cmd);
    if(c.cmd == "GET_TEMPLATE"){
       //respond with the template referenced by c.selector
       sendResponse($(c.selector).outerHTML);
    }
});
```

**content.js**

```
var command = {cmd:"GET_TEMPLATE", selector:"#template-1"};
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(JSON.stringify(command), function(response) {
    //and here you should get your template
    console.log(response);
    //you can start using jQuery like $(response) to alter it
});
```

This method has worked flawlessly for me. I not only use commands here but I use them everywhere now, it works well with message passing.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the [web_accessible_resources](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources) manifest setting, then in your content script you can just inject a `link` element that points to the `chrome.extension.getURL(<filename>)` value for the CSS, and inject a `script` element of type `text/html` with an id, and then fetch the contents of that node and use those for your `appendChild` call.